# Linux Kernel: udelay() returns too early?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, delayed-execution

I have a driver which requires microsecond delays. To create this delay, my driver is using the kernel's udelay function. Specifically, there is one call to udelay(90):

```
iowrite32(data, addr + DATA_OFFSET);
iowrite32(trig, addr + CONTROL_OFFSET);

udelay(30);

trig |= 1;
iowrite32(trig, addr + CONTROL_OFFSET);

udelay(90); // This is the problematic call
```

We had reliability issues with the device. After a lot of debugging, we traced the problem to the driver resuming before 90us has passed. (See "proof" below.)

I am running kernel version 2.6.38-11-generic SMP (Kubuntu 11.04, x86_64) on an Intel Pentium Dual Core (E5700).

As far as I know, the documentation states that udelay will delay execution for *at least* the specified delay, and is uninterruptible. **Is there a bug is this version of the kernel, or did I misunderstand something about the use of udelay?**

---

To convince ourselves that the problem was caused by udelay returning too early, we fed a 100kHz clock to one of the I/O ports and implemented our own delay as follows:

```
// Wait until n number of falling edges
// are observed
void clk100_delay(void *addr, u32 n) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        u32 prev_clk = ioread32(addr);
        while (1) {
            u32 clk = ioread32(addr);
            if (prev_clk && !clk) {
                break;
            } else {
                prev_clk = clk;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...and the driver now works flawlessly.

---

As a final note, I found [a discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.ports.arm.kernel/78496) indicating that frequency scaling could be causing the *delay() family of functions to misbehave, but this was on a ARM mailing list - I assuming such problems would be non-existent on a Linux x86 based PC.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any bug in that version of the kernel (but that doesn't mean that there isn't one).

`udelay()` isn't "uninterruptible" - it does not disable preemption, so your task can be preempted by a RT task during the delay.  However the same is true of your alternate delay implementation, so that is unlikely to be the problem.

Could your actual problem be a DMA coherency / memory ordering issue?  Your alternate delay implementation accesses the bus, so this might be hiding the real problem as a side-effect.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant by "uninterruptible" was that the call should only return once the delay is up.

In this driver, I am not using DMA.

As for cache coherency issues, the device is a PCI-Express FPGA. When probing the device, I request for it's I/O region and use ioremap_nocache() to get the base address used in all the I/O functions. I thought using ioremap_nocache() ensures cache coherency?

Answer (score 2):

The E5700 has `X86_FEATURE_CONSTANT_TSC` but not `X86_FEATURE_NONSTOP_TSC`.  The TSC is the likely clock source for the `udelay`.  Unless bound to one of the cores with an affinity mask, your task may have been preempted and rescheduled to another CPU during the `udelay`.  Or the TSC might not be stable during lower-power CPU modes.

Can you try disabling interrupts or disabling preemption during the `udelay`?  Also, try reading the TSC before and after.

Comment: I will try it out and get back to you. Just so I understand you right, each core has its own TSC, so if the process my driver is servicing got rescheduled to another CPU, the TSC might not be the same?

Also, do I understand correctly that X86_FEATURE_CONSTANT_TSC signifies that the CPU's TSC is stable regardless of frequency scaling, and X86_FEATURE_NONSTOP_TSC means the TSC will never stop counting? If so, when would a CPU halt it's TSC?

Comment: The TSC may halt during certain [C-States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Processor_states).

Comment: The [TSC-based delay code](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/arch/x86/lib/delay.c#L51) properly accounts for being shifted between CPUs during the delay.  The TSC stopping during the delay would just make the delay *longer*, not *shorter*, so that isn't the problem either.