# How can I prove __udelay() is working correctly on my ARM embedded system?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded

We have an ARM9 using the 3.2 kernel -- everything seems to work fine. Recently I was asked to add some code to add a 50ms pulse on some GPIO lines at startup. The pulse code is fine; I can see the lines go down and up, as expected. What does not work the way I expected is the `udelay()` function. Reading the docs makes me think the units are in microseconds, but as measured in the logic analyzer it was way too short. So I finally added this code to get 50ms.

```
// wait 50ms to be sure PCIE reset takes
for (i=0;i<6100;i++) // measured on logic analyzer - seems wrong to me!!
{
   __udelay(2000); // 2000 is max
}
```

I don't like it, but it works fine. There are some odd constants and instructions in the `udelay` code. Can someone enlighten me as to how this is supposed to work? This code is called after all the clocks are initialized, so everything else seems ok.

Answer (score 4):

According to Linus in [this thread](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1325037):

> If it's about 1% off, it's all fine. If somebody picked a delay value 
>   that is so sensitive to small errors in the delay that they notice 
>   that - or even notice something like 5% - then they have picked too 
>   short of a delay.
>
> udelay() was never really meant to be some kind of precision 
>   instrument. Especially with CPU's running at different frequencies, 
>   we've historically had some rather wild fluctuation. The traditional 
>   busy loop ends up being affected not just by interrupts, but also by 
>   things like cache alignment (we used to inline it), and then later the
>   TSC-based one obviously depended on TSC's being stable (which they 
>   weren't for a while).
>
> So historically, we've seen udelay() being *really* off (ie 50% off 
>   etc), I wouldn't worry about things in the 1% range.
>
> Linus

So it's not going to be perfect. It's going to be off. By how much is dependent on a lot of factors. Instead of using a `for` loop, consider using `mdelay` instead. It might be a bit more accurate. From the [O'Reilly Linux Device Drivers](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch06.html) book:

> The *udelay* call should be called only for short time lapses because
>   the precision of `loops_per_second` is only eight bits, and noticeable
>   errors accumulate when calculating long delays. Even though the
>   maximum allowable delay is nearly one second (since calculations
>   overflow for longer delays), the suggested maximum value for *udelay* is
>   1000 microseconds (one millisecond). The function *mdelay* helps in
>   cases where the delay must be longer than one millisecond.
>
> It's also important to remember that *udelay* is a busy-waiting function
>   (and thus *mdelay* is too); other tasks can't be run during the time
>   lapse. You must therefore be very careful, especially with *mdelay*, and
>   avoid using it unless there's no other way to meet your goal.
>
> Currently, support for delays longer than a few microseconds and
>   shorter than a timer tick is very inefficient. This is not usually an
>   issue, because delays need to be just long enough to be noticed by
>   humans or by the hardware. One hundredth of a second is a suitable
>   precision for human-related time intervals, while one millisecond is a
>   long enough delay for hardware activities.

Specifically the line "**the suggested maximum value for *udelay* is 1000 microseconds (one millisecond)**" sticks out at me since you state that 2000 is the max. From [this document](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/timers/timers-howto.txt) on inserting delays:

> mdelay is macro wrapper around udelay, to account for possible
>   overflow when passing large arguments to udelay

So it's possible you're running into an overflow error. Though I wouldn't normally consider 2000 to be a "large argument".

But if you need real accuracy in your timing, you'll need to deal with the offset like you have, roll your own or use a different kernel. For information on how to roll your own delay function using assembler or using hard real time kernels, see this article on [High-resolution timing](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/IO-Port-Programming-4.html).

See also: [Linux Kernel: udelay() returns too early?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352812/linux-kernel-udelay-returns-too-early)

Comment: On modern kernels hrtimer_nanosleep should be portable enough.

Comment: @cdleonard `nanosleep` may use `udelay` in it's busy loop depending on the scheduler mode and delay length. See the link I provided on [High-resolution timing](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/IO-Port-Programming-4.html).

Comment: @embedded.kyle - really appreciate your answering, but I'm not satisfied. mdelay just calls udelay in a for loop, so it's no help. And the amount udelay is off is nowhere near 1% or 50% - I was expecting a loop counter of 25 if everything worked perfect (2ms each loop). If it was 50% off - than my loop would be 50. But 6100? That's so far away, it bothers me a lot. Thanks again, but I'm still on a quest :)

Comment: @Jeff Maybe the [BogoMips](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/BogoMips/bogo-faq.html) or `loops_per_sec` kernel variable is off. Take a peak and see if they seem reasonable.

Comment: Nice answer, that explains the issues I'm currently encountering. Thank you.